# How to give Angular Material button individual position on website?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to render a material button on the right hand side of the website. The button is by default on the left hand side. I wrapped the button with a div and gave the div a SCSS class. The result was that the button is kind of in the middle of the website now not on the left anymore.

So here is my SCSS

```
.save-button {
  display: flex;
  width: 490px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

This is the code from my HTML template

```
<div class="save-button">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="savePost()">Save Post</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this Problem!

It was as easy as just adding `justify-content: flex-end;` to my SCSS class.